# Is it possible to make POST/Update request at selected hour? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im wondering if its possible to make something like POST/Update request at selected by user(admin) hour. Something simillar to facebook' mechanics where you can set hour when exactly you will post a post from your fanpage. To be more clear: I have commentary section for users where they can check what's going on before their shift. I want to make admin able to set hour(maybe write like: 10:20 or 19:40) then write a comment " xxxx " and then click at the POST button which will obviously POST/Update a request at that hour. What do you think?

Thanks for any try to help <3

Comment: Yes, but not really possible in your client-side application. The way to do this is by making a POST request immediately that schedules a backend job to create the comment at some point in the future.

Comment: Hmm.. Could you tell me more about it? Would you have any guide for this?

Comment: What language is your API written in? There are many different tools and libraries for doing this type of thing.

Comment: Its a MERN stack so mostly NodeJS, expressJS and mongoDB

Comment: I would look at things like [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) or [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule)

Comment: I will surely do! Thank you so much! <3

Comment: why not using `cron`? if you use nodeJS you can simplify the entire process by using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron